# Adding an array in embedded x86 assembly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly coding and embedding it in C++, the thing I'm trying to do is add the integers in an array using assembly. This is the code i have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int x [] = {5,4,3,2,1};
int sumArray(int [5]);
int main()
{
    sumArray(x);
    printf_s("The sum of the array is %d");
}
int sumArray(int [5])
{
    __asm
    {
        mov edi,OFFSET sumArray
        mov ecx,5
        mov eax,0
    L1:
        add eax,[edi]
        add edi, TYPE sumArray
        loop L1
    }
}
```

An original problem I was having with was with **mov ecx** I had it as

`mov ecx,LENGTHOF sumArray`

but it wouldn't compile so I changed it to 5 and it compiled. So now when I run the program it breaks. I used F11 in Visual Studio to go line by line to see at what line the program breaks, and program breaks when its going through the loop a second time.

So if anyone can help me figure out how I can go about fixing it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you have it broken quite a bit. First of all, you have a *function* named `sumArray` with an *unnamed* argument. But inside the function, you are referring to `sumArray` as if it were the name of the array argument. Then, you need to understand the way C(++) passes arrays as arguments: they are (always) passed by reference, as a pointer to the first array member. And it also means the function (in general) does not know the length of the array (unless you set it to a fixed-size). So, you usually pass the length in another argument. Which means we have the following:

```
int sumArray(int arr[], int len)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov edi, arr
        mov ecx, len
        xor eax, eax
    L1:
        add eax, [edi]
        add edi, 4
        loop L1
    }
}
```

Note that we are not trying to get an *offset* of the array, that would get us to the pointer, we need to get the value of the pointer, i.e. the address of the first array item. Also, note I have hardcoded the element size (4), there is no point acting like we can work with anything, if at the previous line, we add 32-bit words. (The `xor eax, eax` is just another way to set a register to zero, to be honest, in today’s CPUs, I am not sure if it is faster or not.)

And when testing this, do not forget to actually pass the result to the `printf_s`…

Comment: I addition I believe that the cdecl calling convention on windows (and I presume from the assembly syntax that it's windows), requires you to save the edi register across calls. I doubt the compiler is going to do that for you if it's only used in the assembly part (but I've not checked)

Comment: @JohnB Nope, you don't need to preserve it manually - compiler will make it for you when your are using inline assembly - [Using and Preserving Registers in Inline Assembly at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx): "When using __asm to write assembly language in C/C++ functions, you don't need to preserve the EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers..."

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code seems to be you are using your `sumArray` function name instead of your actual array `x`, and thats why it crashes.

Isn't your asm supposed to look like these:

```
__asm
{
    mov edi,OFFSET x
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF x
    mov eax,0
L1:
    add eax,[edi]
    add edi, TYPE x
    loop L1
}
```

? (here I assume, that you are not mistaken about macro usage, as I never compiled anything using MASM, that seems to be used here, but I think you got the idea)

The another question is why you pass unnamed argument to `sumArray` if you don't actually use it, you'd better then pass the array as a named argument and it's length and make use of them in your assembly code.

Comment: @Mormegil and @asciz thanks for the help, but when I was trying to use the examples provided they were not working all that much so I blended the two and it was working fine. Here's what is working for me:

`int sumArray(int x[])`
`{`
 `__asm`
 `{`
  `mov edi,x`
  `mov ecx,5`
  `xor eax,eax`
 `L1:`
  `add eax,[edi]`
  `add edi,TYPE x`
  `loop L1`
 `}`
`}`

well both of you and the other people that are posting help me out a lot so thank you all and now ill be moving on to my next problem which is getting the `printf_s` to read the answer.